# Angular directive calls function passed by isolated scope (ngclickfunction:'&') works fine but browser gives: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a button directive I want to reuse along my site.

```
    daniboomerangDirectives.directive('button', function() {  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      ngclickfunction: '&'
    },
    template: function (elem, attrs) {
      ...
      if (attrs.onclick == 'function')  { link = '<a id="button-link" href="" ng-click="ngclickfunction()">' + linkContent + '</a>'; }
      ...
      return '<div id="button-wrapper"><div id="button">' + link + '</div></div>';
    }
  };
});
```

The idea is that the ng-click function is passed by the one who uses the button directive, and the button directive calls the function passed by the parent via ngclickfunction: '&' when the user clicks in the `<a>` element of the button

```
.directive('daniboomerangIntro', function($timeout, $rootScope, $compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'views/intro.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var introButtonStartAppHtml = '<div button id="start-button" contenttype="text" text="START" statepressed="false" onclick="function" ngclickfunction="startApp()"></div>';
      introCenter.append(introButtonStartAppHtml);
      $compile(introCenter)(scope);

      scope.startApp = function(){
        ...
      }
```

The thing is that everything works fine. The parent scope function `startApp()` works fine, is executed correctly.
However, I get this:

On Safari: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'         (anonymous function)`

On Chrome: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } (index):2`

On Firefox: `'SyntaxError: function statement requires a name  (localhost:8080:1:8)`

If I put the ng-click in the parent directive at the button directive element I don´t get the browser error.

```
var introButtonStartAppHtml = '<div button id="start-button" contenttype="text" text="START" statepressed="false" ng-click="startApp()"></div>';
```

My problem here is that I don´t know how to keep looking into it. There is no file to debug, line of code that triggers the error...
How would you proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems (frankly, I did not analyse your code, just glimpsed over it - so I might by very wrong) that the error is triggered by the fact that the `onclick` attribute (parsed by the browser as Javascript code) contains a reserved keyword: `function` in a context that is not parseable. Any instantiation of DOM from the string will end in an exception. Since you seem to be using the keyword as a sort of a magic string, why don't you try to change it, either to some other name (then the javascript should parse, although it will not execute) or change the attribute name to anything else?

Comment: You got it dude.

Thanks a lot ;)